# Serve ReactDOM.render page with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a script (App.js) that exports to a ReactDOM.render() (index.js) in order to serve a page. I have a Ubuntu server running Nginx as a reverse proxy and am wondering how I can have this rendered page served through Nginx.

My current (simplified) Nginx server configuration (sites-available):

```
server {
        root path/to/build;

        server_name name www.name;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
     }
```

I am running this with create-react-app and `npm run build` + `serve -s build` but am unsure if this is the way I should be going about it.

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My goal is to just have my singular page accessible through my URL; currently, all it displays is an empty page. I am assuming this is because it is serving the empty build .HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to run your frontend application via `NGINX` is building / bundling it to a `dist` or `build` folder by running `npm run build`. This folder will be used by nginx, it contains `html`, `css` and `js` files. If you set the `root` within your `nginx.conf` to the folder that was build or move the contents to where `nginx.conf` is referring to you will see your application.
This means you can also drop your current config in `server {`

Comment: This is what I currently have, but it displays an empty page. I believe this only works if the page is purely static, no? If the page is being rendered through ReactDOM, the built index.html wouldn't have the proper page to display, which is the problem I am trying to fix.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `proxy_pass` parameter